# What is the purpose of having a didInvalidate property in the data structure of a react-redux app's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, react-redux

I'm learning from the react-redux docs on middleware and have trouble understanding the purpose of the `didInvalidate` property in the [reddit example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html). It seems like the example goes through the middleware to let the store now the process of making an API call starting with `INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT` then to `REQUEST_POSTS` then to `RECEIVE_POSTS`. Why is the `INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT` necessary? Looking at the actions below, I can only guess that it prevents multiple fetches from happening in case the user clicks 'refresh' very rapidly. Is that the only purpose of this property?

```
function shouldFetchPosts(state, subreddit) {
  const posts = state.postsBySubreddit[subreddit]
  if (!posts) {
    return true
  } else if (posts.isFetching) {
    return false
  } else {
    return posts.didInvalidate
  }
}

export function fetchPostsIfNeeded(subreddit) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (shouldFetchPosts(getState(), subreddit)) {
      return dispatch(fetchPosts(subreddit))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are close that `didInvalidate` is related to reducing server requests, however it is kind of the opposite of preventing fetches. It informs the app it *should* go and fetch new data; the current data did 'invalidate'.

Knowing a bit about the lifecycle will help explain further. Redux uses `mapStateToProps` to help to decide whether to redraw a Component when the global state changes.

When a Component is about to be redrawn, because the state (mapped to the props) changes for instance, `componentDidMount` is called. Typically if the state depends on remote data `componentDidMount` checks to see if the state contains a current representation of the remote data (e.g. via `shouldFetchPosts`).

You are correct that it is inefficient to keep making the remote call but it is `shouldFetchPosts` that guards against this. Once the required data has been fetched (`!posts` is false) or it is in the process of being fetched (`isFetching` is true) then the check `shouldFetchPosts` returns false.

Once there is a set of `posts` in the state then the app will never fetch another set from the server.

But what happens when the server side data changes? The app will typically provide a refresh button, which (as components should not change the state) issues an 'Action' (`INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT` for example) which is reduced into setting a flag (`posts.didInvalidate`) in the state that indicates that the data is now invalid.

The change in state triggers the component redraw which, as mentioned, checks `shouldFetchPosts` which falls into the clause that executes `return posts.didInvalidate` which is now true, therefore firing the action to `REQUEST_POSTS` and fetching the current server side data.

So to reiterate: `didInvalidate` suggests a fetch of the current server side data is needed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the implementation of invalidation very well. Having to press a Refresh button is bad UX, according to me. How do sites manage this syncing, then? Does the back send a socket message, for example, saying that such and such resource id has changed? I doubt it's done through Web Sockets, though, because then the server would also send the content, and http requests won't be needed.

Comment: @dotslash, you could use sockets to inform the frontend that the data it has is now invalid - and it should fetch fresh data (not an uncommon pattern). Alternatively (as you mention) you could map certain ws messages  to actions that update the state from some data in the message payload.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't all this add a lot of (unnecessary) complexity to the backend? Isn't server-rendered pages a simpler solution? I can't help but think about these things. O.o

Answer (score 5):

The most up-voted answer isn't entirely correct.

`didInvalidate` is used to tell the app whether the data is stale or not. If `true`, the data should be re-fetched from the server. If `false`, we will use the data we already have.

In the official examples, firing `INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT` will set `didInvalidate` to true. This Redux action can be dispatched as a result of a user action (clicking a refresh button), or something else (a countdown, a server push etc.)

However, **firing `INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT` alone will not initiate a new request to the server**. It is simply used to determine whether we should re-fetch the data or use the existing data when we call `fetchPostsIfNeeded()`.

Because `didInvalidate` is set to `true`, the app will not let us fetch the data more than once. To refresh our data (e.g. after clicking a refresh button) we need to:

```
dispatch(invalidateSubreddit(selectedSubreddit))
dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
```

Because we called `invalidateSubreddit()`, `didInvalidate` is set to `true` and `fetchPostsIfNeeded()` will initiate a re-fetch.

(This is why danmux's answer isn't entirely correct. The life cycle method `componentDidMount` will not be called when the state (which is mapped to the props) changes; `componentDidMount` is only called when the component mounts for the first time. So, the effect of hitting the refresh button will not appear until the component has been remounted, e.g. from a route change.)